# Проблемы с отправкой формы AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Нужно чтобы при отправке формы пользователь оставался на одной странице, и сообщение об успешной отправке отображается, но у меня всегда есть сообщение о неудачной отправке и данные не отправляются. Подозреваю, что неправильно передаю их в action.php или неправильно обрабатываю. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, уже вообще вариантов не осталось.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь в решении данной проблемы.

**САМА ФОРМА**

```
<br/>
<div class="statusMsg"></div>
<br/>
<form method="post" id="fupForm" action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Ваше имя</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Иван Петрович" >
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Ваш Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="image">Изображение:<br>
        </label>    
        <input type="file" name="image" id="file">
        <p class="help-block">Допустимый формат jpg/gif/png, допустимый размер - не более 320х240 пикселей, размер файла не больше 8192КБ </p>
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="task">Задача</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="task" rows="5" placeholder="Текст задачи"></textarea>      
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
        <p><!-- Модальное окно-->   
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="button_Preview" id="button_Preview" value='Предварительный просмотр' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Preview">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <p><input type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="upload" value='Сохранить задачу'></p>
    </div>  
</form>
```

**AJAX-скрипт**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("#fupForm").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'action.php',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#btn_submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
            $('#fupForm').css("opacity",".5");
        },
        success: function(msg){
            $('.statusMsg').html('');
            if(msg == 'ok'){
                $('#fupForm')[0].reset();
                $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#34A853">Form data submitted successfully.</span>');
            }else{
                $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#EA4335">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
            }
            $('#fupForm').css("opacity","");
            $("#btn_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

});

**И обработчик action.php**

```
    <?php
if ((isset($_POST['upload']) == 1) && ($_FILES['image']['size']) > 0)
{
  $msg_box = ""; // в этой переменной будем хранить сообщения формы
  // Код, который будет выполняться, если форма была оправлена:

    // подключение к базе данных
    // (возможно, вам придется настроить имя хоста, имя пользователя и пароль)
  $dbh = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "tasker");

  if(mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    exit("Ошибка подключения к базе данных MySQL: Сервер база данных не доступен!<br>
      Проверте параметры подключения к базе данных.");
  }

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $task = $_POST['task'];


  $sPhotoFileName = $_FILES['image']['name']; // get client side file name
if ($sPhotoFileName) // file uploaded
{ $aFileNameParts = explode(".", $sPhotoFileName);
  $sFileExtension = end($aFileNameParts); // part behind last dot
  if ($sFileExtension != "jpg"
    && $sFileExtension != "JPEG"
    && $sFileExtension != "JPG" 
    && $sFileExtension != "png"
    && $sFileExtension != "PNG"
    && $sFileExtension != "gif"
    && $sFileExtension != "GIF")
    { die ("Choose a JPG, PNG, GIF for the photo");
}
  $nPhotoSize = $_FILES['image']['size']; // size of uploaded file
  if ($nPhotoSize == 0)
    { die ("Sorry. The upload of $sPhotoFileName has failed.
      Search a photo smaller than 100K, using the button.");
}
if ($nPhotoSize > 10240000000)
  { die ("Sorry.
    The file $sPhotoFileName is larger than 100K.
    Advice: reduce the photo using a drawing tool.");
}
  // read photo
  $sTempFileName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; // temporary file at server side
  $oTempFile = fopen($sTempFileName, "r");
  $sBinaryPhoto = fread($oTempFile, fileSize($sTempFileName));
  // Try to read image
  $nOldErrorReporting = error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_WARNING)); // ingore warnings
  $oSourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($sBinaryPhoto); // try to create image
  error_reporting($nOldErrorReporting);
  if (!$oSourceImage) // error, image is not a valid jpg
  { die ("Sorry.
    It was not possible to read photo $sPhotoFileName.
    Choose another photo.");
}
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$nWidth = imagesx($oSourceImage); // get original source image width
  $nHeight = imagesy($oSourceImage); // and height
  // create small thumbnail
  $nDestinationWidth = 320;
  $nDestinationHeight = 240;
  $oDestinationImage = imagecreate($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);
  imagecopyresized($oDestinationImage, $oSourceImage,0, 0, 0, 0,$nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight,$nWidth, $nHeight); // resize the image
  ob_start(); // Start capturing stdout.
  imageJPEG($oDestinationImage); // As though output to browser.
  $sBinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents(); // the raw jpeg image data.
  ob_end_clean(); // Dump the stdout so it does not screw other output.

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if($_POST['upload'])
  {

    $sBinaryThumbnail = addslashes($sBinaryThumbnail);
    $result=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user (username,email,task,bin_data,filename,filesize,filetype) 
      "."VALUES ('".$username."',
      '".$email."',
      '".$task."',
      '".$sBinaryThumbnail."',
      '".$_FILES["image"]["name"]."',
      '".$size."',
      '".$_FILES["image"]["type"]."')");

    //if(!$result) exit("Ошибка выполнения SQL запроса!");
    echo $result?'ok':'err';

    $result->execute(); 

  }
}
```

Comment: Добрый день. Думаю, что первая ошибка у Вас в строке data: new FormData(this),

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я тоже подозреваю, что передаю неправильно данные в обработчик. Можете подсказать как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы нормально отдавать ошибки от обработчика формы, я бы передавал в ответ json с типом сообщения и её текстом. На стороне js отправка данных формы идет без ошибок. Немного нужно изменить прием ответа от `action.php` в js.

Файл **action.php**

```
function returnMessage($message){
    echo json_encode($message);
    exit();
}

$message = [];
if ($_FILES['image']['size'] <= 0){
    $message['type'] = 'error';
    $message['text'] = '$_FILES[\'image\'][\'size\'] > 0'; // текст ошибки
    returnMessage($message);
}

$sPhotoFileName = $_FILES['image']['name']; // get client side file name
// file uploaded
if (!$sPhotoFileName){
    $message['type'] = 'error';
    $message['text'] = 'FALSE TO GET $_FILES[\'image\'][\'name\']'; // текст ошибки
    returnMessage($message);
}

$aFileNameParts = explode(".", $sPhotoFileName);
$sFileExtension = end($aFileNameParts); // part behind last dot
if ($sFileExtension != "jpg"
    && $sFileExtension != "JPEG"
    && $sFileExtension != "JPG" 
    && $sFileExtension != "png"
    && $sFileExtension != "PNG"
    && $sFileExtension != "gif"
    && $sFileExtension != "GIF")
{
    $message['type'] = 'error';
    $message['text'] = 'INVALID FILE EXTENSION'; // текст ошибки
    returnMessage($message);
}
$nPhotoSize = $_FILES['image']['size']; // size of uploaded file
if ($nPhotoSize == 0){
    $message['type'] = 'error';
    $message['text'] = 'Sorry. The upload of '.$sPhotoFileName.' has failed. Search a photo smaller than 100K, using the button'; // текст ошибки
    returnMessage($message);
}
if ($nPhotoSize > 10240000000){
    $message['type'] = 'error';
    $message['text'] = 'Sorry. The file '.$sPhotoFileName.' is larger than 100K. Advice: reduce the photo using a drawing tool.'; // текст ошибки
    returnMessage($message);
}

// read photo
$sTempFileName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; // temporary file at server side
$oTempFile = fopen($sTempFileName, "r");
$sBinaryPhoto = fread($oTempFile, fileSize($sTempFileName));
// Try to read image
$nOldErrorReporting = error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_WARNING)); // ingore warnings
$oSourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($sBinaryPhoto); // try to create image
error_reporting($nOldErrorReporting);

// error, image is not a valid jpg
if (!$oSourceImage){
    $message['type'] = 'error';
    $message['text'] = 'Sorry. It was not possible to read photo '.$sPhotoFileName.'. Choose another photo.'; // текст ошибки
    returnMessage($message);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$nWidth = imagesx($oSourceImage); // get original source image width
$nHeight = imagesy($oSourceImage); // and height
// create small thumbnail
$nDestinationWidth = 320;
$nDestinationHeight = 240;
$oDestinationImage = imagecreate($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);
imagecopyresized($oDestinationImage, $oSourceImage,0, 0, 0, 0,$nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight,$nWidth, $nHeight); // resize the image
ob_start(); // Start capturing stdout.
imageJPEG($oDestinationImage); // As though output to browser.
$sBinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents(); // the raw jpeg image data.
ob_end_clean(); // Dump the stdout so it does not screw other output.


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$task = $_POST['task'];

if(!isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $message['type'] = 'error';
    $message['text'] = 'NOT ISSET $_POST[\'upload\']'; // текст ошибки
    returnMessage($message);
}

$dbh = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "tasker");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    $message['type'] = 'error';
    $message['text'] = 'Ошибка подключения к базе данных MySQL: Сервер база данных не доступен!<br>Проверте параметры подключения к базе данных'; // текст ошибки
    returnMessage($message);
}

$sBinaryThumbnail = addslashes($sBinaryThumbnail);
$result=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user (username,email,task,bin_data,filename,filesize,filetype) 
  "."VALUES ('".$username."',
  '".$email."',
  '".$task."',
  '".$sBinaryThumbnail."',
  '".$_FILES["image"]["name"]."',
  '".$size."',
  '".$_FILES["image"]["type"]."')");

$result = $result->execute();

if(!$result){
    $message['type'] = 'error';
    $message['text'] = 'Ошибка выполнения SQL запроса!'; // текст ошибки
    returnMessage($message);
}

$message['type'] = 'success';
$message['text'] = 'GOOD';
returnMessage($message);
```

Сама форма и js:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("#fupForm").on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'action.php',
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    beforeSend: function(){
     $('#btn_submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
     $('#fupForm').css("opacity",".5");
     $('.statusMsg').html('');
    },
    success: function(msg){
     msg = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
     if(msg.type == 'success'){
      $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#34A853">Form data submitted successfully.</span>');
     }else{
      $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#EA4335">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span><p>'+msg.text+'</p>');
     }
     $('#fupForm').css("opacity","");
     $("#btn_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
   });
  });
 });
```

```html
<div class="statusMsg"></div>
 <form method="post" id="fupForm" action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="username">Ваше имя</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Иван Петрович" >
  </div>    
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="email">Ваш Email</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" >
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">    
   <label for="image">Изображение:<br>
   </label>    
   <input type="file" name="image" id="file">
   <p class="help-block">Допустимый формат jpg/gif/png, допустимый размер - не более 320х240 пикселей, размер файла не больше 8192КБ </p>
  </div>   
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="task">Задача</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="task" rows="5" placeholder="Текст задачи"></textarea>      
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
   <p><!-- Модальное окно-->   
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="button_Preview" id="button_Preview" value='Предварительный просмотр' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Preview">
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
   <p><input type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="upload" value='Сохранить задачу'></p>
  </div>  
 </form>
```

На тесте у меня работает передача данных через ajax, возврат сообщения отработки формы, его разбор в js и отображения пользователю. НЕ проверялась логика обработки данных формы и внесение в БД

Comment: Добрый день! 
Ваш код возвращает с сервера значение error при обработке формы.

Comment: Проставьте тексты ответов (в некоторых проверках я оставил его пустым) $message['text'] в файле action.php и посмотрите где в логике обработке формы есть ошибки. Текст ответа при типе обратного сообщения error должен выводиться в div.statusMsg

Comment: Не  совсем Вас понимаю, можете навести пример проверки, пожалуйста?

Comment: В конечном итоге выводит {"type":"success","text":"GOOD"}, т.е. в action.php он проходит до конца. Значит  проверки он проходит успешно, правильно понимаю?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Внес все тексты сообщений об ошибках

Comment: Правильно. Значит все проверки пройдены и данных внесены в БД. Заметьте, что условия проверок я, практически, не менял. Они остались Ваши

Comment: Выдает, что NOT ISSET $_POST['upload'] OR $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0. И теперь не добавляет в БД данные.

Comment: При отладке путем <pre>
  <?php print_r(isset($_POST['upload'])) ; ?>
</pre>
Выдает 1, но если поставить !, то выдает пустоту.

Comment: Обновил action.php. Не передается name=upload. Не нужно тогда проверять. Смотрите уже Вашу логику обработки данных с формы

Comment: Убрал проверку еще одну на upload и все заработало, спасибо. Но всё-таки интересно почему не передается name=upload...

Comment: Подозреваю, что это прикол с "data: new FormData(this)". Без использования ajax, есть передача name=upload. Если ответ решил вопрос, отметьте его

Comment: Извините еще раз, но случилась какая-то ерунда. В пути моих манипуляций с файлами сломалась отправка формы, а именно при отправке вся страница становится полупрозрачной, и так остается, но данные отправляются. Скрипт тот же, ничего не менял, вроде. С чем это может быть связано? Сообщения тоже не возвращаются никакие.

Comment: Вот что пишет  в логе:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (common.js:35)
    at fire (jquery-3.3.1.js:3268)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.js:3398)
    at done (jquery-3.3.1.js:9305)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.js:9548)

Comment: В файле action.php идет ответ не в формате json. Проверьте возврат текстов ошибок. они должны быть в формате json (type, text)

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!!!

Answer (score 1):

Правильней будет сделать так. 
Сначала собрать данные из обычных полей, потом собрать данные с поля file и уже после этого передать в ajax запрос.
Это будет выглядеть так

```
$(function() {
    $('#form-data').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var form = $(this); // Предположу, что этот код выполняется в обработчике события 'submit' формы
        var data = new FormData();  // Для отправки файлов понадобится объект FormData. Подробнее про него можно прочитать в документации - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
        // Сбор данных из обычных полей
        form.find(':input[name]').not('[type="file"]').each(function() { 
            var field = $(this);
            data.append(field.attr('name'), field.val());
        });
        // Сбор данных о файле (будет немного отличаться для нескольких файлов)
        var filesField = form.find('input[type="file"]');
        var fileName = filesField.attr('name');
        var file = filesField.prop('files')[0];
        data.append(fileName, file) ;
        // Отправка данных
        var url = 'upload.php';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false, 
            processData:false, 
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            }           
        });  
    })          
});
```

Проблема возврата ответа сервера у Вас в echo **$result?'ok':'err';**
Выполняйте запрос и если запрос выполняется успешно, то возвращайте что-то подобное

```
if($result->execute()){
   $answer = ['type' => 'success', 'text' => 'Success'];
}
else{
  $answer = ['type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error'];
}
```

На стороне клиента уже разобрать этот ответ

```
success: function(data){
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
    if(response.type == 'success'{
       /*******
    }
    if(response.type == 'error'){
      /****
    }      
}
```

Comment: Данные отправляет, в таблицу mysql все заносится, все отлично, но на экран все время выводится сообщение об неудачной отправке формы. Могу лишь предположить, что проверка на возврат значения из обработчика не работает...

Comment: сделайте console.log(msg) и посмотрите, что возвращается.

Comment: обновил ответ, отправляйте ответ после успешного запроса к базе

Comment: Выводил в консоль msg и показало, что возвращается ok, но сообщение все равно выводится ошибочное. Так же исправил то, чтобы отправлял ответ после успешного запроса к базе, но все тоже самое получается... Вероятно, проблема в проверке на 'ok', не знаю...

Comment: Это простейший вариант. Более правильный вариант это возвращать json и уже на стороне клиента распарсивать его при помощи jQuery.parseJSON

Comment: ещё раз обновил ответ

Comment: Не знаю уже, либо я неправильно как-то реализовываю Ваш код, но сейчас вообще не выводится никаких сообщений ))

Comment: Лог:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (common.js:114)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: возвращать надо через echo json_encode($answer)